# How to create a wrapper class for node.js plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, wrapper, nuxt.js

So I'm new to JavaScript, and have a project where I'm using the [Node.js cookies module found here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies) I've been able to create cookies & set them correctly like so:

```
this.Vue.$cookies.set('cookieName', cookieValue, {
          sameSite: 'lax',
          secure: true
});
```

However, I want to create a wrapper function/class so I can set the `sameSite: 'lax'` and `secure: true` options as defaults, and not have to pass them in every time I call the `set` function from that module. Obviously, I also want to be able to overwrite those options to something else if I want.

Looking through examples I've found elsewhere, I think the class should look something *vaguely* like this:

```
const cookies = require('cookie-universal-nuxt');

cookies(function ($) {

    const defaultOptions = {
        sameSite: 'lax',
        secure: true
    };

    return {
        get: function(name, options) {
            return $.cookies(name, options)
        },

        set: function (name, value, options) {
            $.cookies(name, value, // somehow options & defaultOptions are passed in and merged here)
        },
    };
});
```

However, this might be totally wrong. Like I said, I'm new to JS, so I'm pretty lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a class for this - a simple wrapper function will probably do what you need. Here's how to create a little factory function that creates a wrapper bound to a specific context:

```
function makeSetCookie($) {
  return function(name, value, options) {
    const defaultOptions = {
      sameSite: 'lax',
      secure: true
    }; 

    $.set(name, value, Object.assign(defaultOptions, options));
 }
}

const setCookie = makeSetCookie(this.Vue /* or whatever */);
// and now you can use setCookie wherever
```

The caller can pass or not pass a value for the `options` param. The line `Object.assign(defaultOptions, options)` copies all keys/values from `options` to `defaultOptions`, overwriting any keys already in defaultOptions (sameSite, secure) if they appear in `options`. If `options` is null or undefined, that's fine - the value returned will just be `defaultOptions`. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I should have been more clear in that I wanted to keep the methods non-static. The context/object I'm calling these off of won't always be exactly `this.Vue`, and I don't want to pass in a parameter to a static function specifying the context. I wanted something like I was asking originally where `$` would represent the context the method would be called off of.

Comment: This won't work properly because the value of `this` in `this.Vue.$cookies` is not correct inside the `setCookie()` function.

Comment: Edited it to reflect requirements given in the comment. Hope this is helpful!