# How to create non-static methods/class that I can call off of multiple objects/contexts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, methods, non-static

So I have a node.js module that I cannot modify that has non-static methods such as `.set`, `.get`, `.remove`, etc. I want to create non-static wrapper methods for these, but want to do it in a way where I can leave the object/context they're being called off of ambiguous.

For example, I currently use these methods like:

```
this.set(name, value, options);
```

and want to recreate a wrapper function where the `this` above may change.

I was thinking it should look something like:

```
export default function($) {

  return {
    set: function (name, value, options) {
      $.set(name, value, options);
    },

    get: function (name) {
      return $.get(name);
    },

    remove: function (name) {
      $.remove(name);
    }
  };
};
```

Where the `$` being passed in is the object/context the method is being called off of (such as but necessarily `this`), but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Is this even possible?

EDIT: As I said in a comment below, I'm trying to default some options so I don't have to constantly specify certain options every time I call the method, and using the wrapper function to do so. I've omitted some code above from inside the wrapper function before the $.set(name, value, options) line is called to make my example more easily understandable since its not relevant to what my question is. Sorry for the confusion - I can see why the wrapper looks unnecessary given the example I gave.

EDIT 2: Here is the link to the original problem I'm trying to solve: 
[How to create a wrapper class for node.js plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121161/how-to-create-a-wrapper-class-for-node-js-plugin/60121759#60121759)

EDIT 3: So I'm an idiot and was accidentally searching my console output for something, which is why it wasn't showing the error message I was receiving all along:

`this.Vue.setCookie is not a function`

Despite my IDE recognizing where the function was coming from, I'm guessing the `setCookie`, `getCookie`, etc. functions are limited to the scope of the function that they're all defined in.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve here?   What is the point of the wrapper.  You've already got a module object that has the desired methods.  Why do you need to wrap it in another object?  The wrapper code you propose looks fine to me if `$` is the module, but I don't see what value it offers or understand what your question really is? Did that work?  Not work? Solve what problem?

Comment: Show how you're using this function.

Comment: I feel like we're being handed an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here where you're describing some solution you came up with without describing the actual problem you are trying to solve.  As with all XY problems, that prevents us from understanding the underlying problem and offering you much better solutions than you've thought of on your own.

Comment: `.bind` first then pass in the argument.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm trying to default some options so I don't have to constantly specify certain options every time I call the method, and using the wrapper function to do so. I've omitted some code above from inside the wrapper function before the `$.set(name, value, options)` line is called to make my example more easily understandable since its not relevant to what my question is. Sorry for the confusion - I can see why the wrapper looks unnecessary given the example I gave.

Comment: The point is that you SHOULD show us what problem you're trying to solve and we can probably offer even better ways to solve it than you've thought of yourself.  I'd suggest you edit your question to both explain WHY and to show your sample code actually doing something useful that you want to accomplish.  That's NOT irrelevant to the question.  That is the core of the problem to be solved here.

Comment: And, what IS the problem with the code you already show that you want help with?  It's just unclear what you want help with?

Comment: Here is the link to the problem I'm actually trying to solve, but given the lack of responses there, as well as revising what I thought might work (above) but didn't, I decided to ask this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121161/how-to-create-a-wrapper-class-for-node-js-plugin/60121759#60121759

Comment: Regardless, while I see your point about being offered better solutions with more context, my original question still stands. I tried the above, and it doesn't work. No compilation errors or anything, it just doesn't seem to work, meaning cookie options/values are not being altered.

Comment: Well, if I use some object in place of `$` with those methods, the wrapper code you show works just fine for me.  Not sure how else to help.  Maybe as Barmar asked an hour ago, if you show us the calling code you're using and what you're passing as `$` that might give us some idea what you're doing wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that, if I read the two questions correctly, should do what you want.  Note that a dummy cookie implementation is included at the bottom.

The trouble is that it looks very much like the code that you supplied; I don't know why that wouldn't work.

```js
// Creates a wrapper for a cookies object such as our `foo.bar.cookies`
const wrapCookies = (cookies, defaults) => ({
  set: (name, value, options) => 
    cookies.set(name, value, Object.assign({}, defaults, options || {})),
  get: (name) => cookies.get(name),
  remove: (name) => cookies.remove(name)
})

console.log('Test the original cookie implementation')
console.log('----------------------------------------')
foo.bar.cookies.set('c1', 'v1', {a: 1})
console.log('c1', foo.bar.cookies.get('c1'))
foo.bar.cookies.set('c2', 'v2', {a: 2})
foo.bar.cookies.remove('c1')


// Create wraper with given defaults
const myCookies = wrapCookies(foo.bar.cookies, {b: 10, c: 42})


console.log(' ')
console.log('Test the wrapper')
console.log('----------------------------------------')
myCookies.set('c3', 'v3', {a: 5})          // defaults `b` and `c`
console.log('c2', myCookies.get('c2'))     // keeps original references
console.log('c3', myCookies.get('c3'))     // handles new references
myCookies.set('c4', 'v4', {a: 7, b: 101})  // overrides `b`
```

```html
<script>
// Dummy implementation for demonstration.
// Saves and logs on `set`, `remove`, just returns on `get`
const foo = {
  bar: {
    cookies: ((storage) => ({
      set: (name, value, options) => {
        console.log(`setting: "${name}" to "${value}" using ${JSON.stringify(options)})}`)
        storage[name] = {value, options}
      },
      get: (name) => storage[name],
      remove: (name) => {
        console.log(`removing: "${name}"`)
        delete storage[name]       
      }
    }))({})
  }
}

</script>
```

If the main question was just how to combine the defaults with your new object, then you probably want to read up on [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

It might also be instructive to look up [`Proxies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).